# Changing a Corda node's name in node.conf is not reflected by the node at runtime

Tags: corda

I have a Corda node that I have already deployed and run. I now want to change the node's name. I do this by changing the node's name in the `node.conf` file.

However, this change is not picked up when I run the node. It continues to use its old name. How can I force the node to use its new name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried above solution of Joel  but unfortunately it didn't worked for me. I am running Azure Single Ledger Network with Corda V2. But here are the steps which worked for me to rename legalName of nodes in an already deployed network on azure.

1. SSH into each node individually including 'network map node' and 'notary node' and run following commands on each node to stop corda servers:

> sudo systemctl stop corda
>
> sudo systemctl stop corda-webserver

2. Edit /opt/corda/node.conf using vim as required in each node. (**Remember:** If you change name of 'network map node' do not forget to change it in all respective nodes on network)

> i.e: myLegalName : "O=MY_ORG_NAME, L=Helsinki, C=FI"

3. Delete persistence using following command:

> rm /opt/corda/persistence.mv.db

4. Delete following certificates:

> rm /opt/corda/certificates/nodekeystore.jks
>
> rm /opt/corda/certificates/sslkeystore.jks

5. Start corda on all nodes using following commands:

   - *I started 'network map node' first and then all others.*

> sudo systemctl start corda
>
> sudo systemctl start corda-webserver

Answer (score 1):

The node's name is specified in the certificates it uses to join the network. The name in `node.conf` is only used when initially requesting these certificates.

If you change the node's name, you must then regenerate its certificates by deleting `nodekeystore.jks` and `sslkeystore.jks` under `./certificates` in the node's folder.

Note that you should only do this in development mode. `nodekeystore.jks` contains the node's identity keypairs. Deleting these may prevent you from spending assets tied to your old keys.